# How to remove HTML Extension from a URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, browser, htmlextensions

Is there any way to remove the **.html** from a **URL**? I haven't host the  site yet. Existing URL is "*file:///E:/SampleWorks/Download.html*" and I would like to change it to "*file:///E:/SampleWorks/Download*". How can I do this?

Comment: First thins first a server

Comment: @MisterPositive — It is a `file:` scheme URL, they aren't using a web server.

Comment: you are opening the file locally, if you don't want the .html extension, rename your file to "Download"

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Changing URLs so they don't map *directly* on to the file system is the province of an HTTP server (which you aren't using).

The only other means to play around with what is displayed in the address bar is [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) but:

- The browser wouldn't find `Download.html` if it had been told to use `Download` and the user hit *refresh*
- Security restrictions on documents loaded over `file:` scheme URIs generally prevent the history API from working

Comment: Ok, but what if i host it locally or something like this 
http://localhost:3020/SampleWorks/Download

Comment: @ArunRajR That looks like the person is using IIS which is a server

Comment: @ArunRajR — then it depends on which server you use

Comment: @Pete : yes i host it locally(in IIS) , so now how can i remove the html extension from my url ? (i mean this ' localhost:3020/SampleWorks/Download.html ' to this ' localhost:3020/SampleWorks/Download ')